C# Source Generation for FeatureDiscovery and EndpointDiscovery
I recently adopted a vertical slices template for our project. The template originally used System.Reflection configuration for discovering and registering features and endpoints. I decided to replace the existing reflection-based approach in the following two classes https://github.com/SSWConsulting/SSW.VerticalSliceArchitecture/blob/main/src/VerticalSliceArchitectureTemplate/Host/EndpointDiscovery.cs and https://github.com/SSWConsulting/SSW.VerticalSliceArchitecture/blob/main/src/VerticalSliceArchitectureTemplate/Host/FeatureDiscovery.cs with source generation.
Given my limited experience with source generation, I am seeking feedback on whether my implementation adheres to best practices for source generation and if there are any improvements I could make.
Original Code Reference

FeatureDiscovery.cs
EndpointDiscovery.cs

Code Overview

FeatureDiscoveryGenerator.cs

This source generator identifies all classes implementing the IFeature interface and generates a FeatureDiscovery class to configure these features.
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text;
// using System.Diagnostics;

namespace VerticalSlices.Api.SourceGenerator;

/// <summary>
/// Source generator that discovers all classes implementing the IFeature interface
/// and generates a FeatureDiscovery class to configure those features.
/// </summary>
[Generator]
public class FeatureDiscoveryGenerator : IIncrementalGenerator
{
    public void Initialize(IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext context)
    {
// #if DEBUG
//         if (!Debugger.IsAttached)
//         {
//             Debugger.Launch();
//         }
// #endif

        // Register a syntax provider that looks for class declarations implementing IFeature
        var featureClasses = context.SyntaxProvider
            .CreateSyntaxProvider(
                predicate: IsClassWithIFeature, // Filter the nodes
                transform: GetClassSemanticModel) // Convert to Semantic Model
            .Where(x => x != null) // Filter out nulls
            .Collect(); // Collect them all

        // Register the source generation step
        context.RegisterSourceOutput(featureClasses, GenerateFeatureDiscoverySource!);
    }

    private static bool IsClassWithIFeature(SyntaxNode node, CancellationToken ct) =>
        node is ClassDeclarationSyntax { BaseList: not null }; // Ensure we have a class declaration with a base list (interfaces or inheritance)

    private static INamedTypeSymbol? GetClassSemanticModel(GeneratorSyntaxContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var classDecl = (ClassDeclarationSyntax)context.Node;

        // Get the semantic model for the class declaration
        var model = context.SemanticModel;
        var classSymbol = model.GetDeclaredSymbol(classDecl);

        // Check if the class implements IFeature
        var implementsIFeature = classSymbol?.AllInterfaces.Any(i => i.Name == "IFeature") ?? false;

        return implementsIFeature ? classSymbol : null;
    }

    private static void GenerateFeatureDiscoverySource(SourceProductionContext context, ImmutableArray<INamedTypeSymbol> classes)
    {
        if (classes.IsDefaultOrEmpty)
        {
            return; // No classes found, skip generation
        }

        // Generate the source code for the discovered classes
        var sourceBuilder = new StringBuilder(@"
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace VerticalSlices.Api.Host
{
    public static class FeatureDiscovery
    {
        public static void ConfigureFeatures(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
");

        foreach (var classSymbol in classes)
        {
            var className = classSymbol.ToDisplayString(); // Get the fully qualified name
            sourceBuilder.AppendLine($"            {className}.ConfigureServices(services, configuration);");
        }

        sourceBuilder.AppendLine(@"
        }
    }
}");

        context.AddSource("FeatureDiscovery.g.cs", SourceText.From(sourceBuilder.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8));
    }
}

Output Example (FeatureDiscovery.g.cs):

using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace VerticalSlices.Api.Host
{
    public static class FeatureDiscovery
    {
        public static void ConfigureFeatures(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            VerticalSlices.Api.Features.Todos.TodoFeature.ConfigureServices(services, configuration);

        }
    }
}


EndpointDiscoveryGenerator.cs

This source generator identifies all classes implementing the IEndpoint interface and generates an EndpointDiscovery class to register these endpoints.
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text;

namespace VerticalSlices.Api.SourceGenerator;

/// <summary>
/// Source generator that discovers all classes implementing the IEndpoint interface
/// and generates an EndpointDiscovery class to register those endpoints.
/// </summary>
[Generator]
public class EndpointDiscoveryGenerator : IIncrementalGenerator
{
    public void Initialize(IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext context)
    {
        // Register a syntax provider that looks for class declarations implementing IEndpoint
        var endpointClasses = context.SyntaxProvider
            .CreateSyntaxProvider(
                predicate: IsClassWithIEndpoint, // Filter the nodes
                transform: GetClassSemanticModel) // Convert to Semantic Model
            .Where(x => x != null) // Filter out nulls
            .Collect(); // Collect them all

        // Register the source generation step
        context.RegisterSourceOutput(endpointClasses, GenerateEndpointDiscoverySource!);
    }

    private static bool IsClassWithIEndpoint(SyntaxNode node, CancellationToken ct) =>
        node is ClassDeclarationSyntax { BaseList: not null }; // Ensure we have a class declaration with a base list (interfaces or inheritance)

    private static INamedTypeSymbol? GetClassSemanticModel(GeneratorSyntaxContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var classDecl = (ClassDeclarationSyntax)context.Node;

        // Get the semantic model for the class declaration
        var model = context.SemanticModel;
        var classSymbol = model.GetDeclaredSymbol(classDecl);

        // Check if the class implements IEndpoint
        var implementsIEndpoint = classSymbol?.AllInterfaces.Any(i => i.Name == "IEndpoint") ?? false;

        return implementsIEndpoint ? classSymbol : null;
    }

    private static void GenerateEndpointDiscoverySource(SourceProductionContext context, ImmutableArray<INamedTypeSymbol> classes)
    {
        if (classes.IsDefaultOrEmpty)
        {
            return; // No classes found, skip generation
        }

        // Generate the source code for the discovered classes
        var sourceBuilder = new StringBuilder(@"
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;

namespace VerticalSlices.Api.Host
{
    public static class EndpointDiscovery
    {
        public static void RegisterEndpoints(this IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
        {
");

        foreach (var classSymbol in classes)
        {
            var className = classSymbol.ToDisplayString(); // Get the fully qualified name
            sourceBuilder.AppendLine($"            {className}.MapEndpoint(endpoints);");
        }

        sourceBuilder.AppendLine(@"
        }
    }
}");

        context.AddSource("EndpointDiscovery.g.cs", SourceText.From(sourceBuilder.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8));
    }
}

Output Example (EndpointDiscovery.g.cs):
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;

namespace VerticalSlices.Api.Host
{
    public static class EndpointDiscovery
    {
        public static void RegisterEndpoints(this IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
        {
            VerticalSlices.Api.Features.Todos.Endpoints.CreateTodoEndpoint.MapEndpoint(endpoints);
            VerticalSlices.Api.Features.Todos.Endpoints.DeleteTodoEndpoint.MapEndpoint(endpoints);
            VerticalSlices.Api.Features.Todos.Endpoints.UpdateTodoEndpoint.MapEndpoint(endpoints);
            VerticalSlices.Api.Features.Todos.Endpoints.CompleteTodoEndpoint.MapEndpoint(endpoints);
            VerticalSlices.Api.Features.Todos.Endpoints.GetTodoEndpoint.MapEndpoint(endpoints);
            VerticalSlices.Api.Features.Todos.Endpoints.GetAllTodosEndpoint.MapEndpoint(endpoints);

        }
    }
}

Questions

I'm using the following configuration to import the source generator project:

<PropertyGroup>
  <!-- Enable output of generated source files to disk -->
  <EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>true</EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <!-- Integrates the source generator with this project -->
  <ProjectReference Include="..\VerticalSlices.Api.SourceGenerator\VerticalSlices.Api.SourceGenerator\VerticalSlices.Api.SourceGenerator.csproj"
                    OutputItemType="Analyzer"
                    ReferenceOutputAssembly="false" />
</ItemGroup>

What's confusing to me is the fact that I have to specify OutputItemType="Analyzer" but the project name is VerticalSlices.Api.SourceGenerator since it's all about the source generation and not code analysis.

Is the syntax provider set up correctly to capture class declarations implementing IFeature and IEndpoint? Is checking for BaseList sufficient, or should additional checks be added?

Are the methods for transforming syntax nodes to semantic models effective? Are there any edge cases or improvements that should be addressed?

Does the implementation follow best practices for source generation? Are there any suggestions for improving the maintainability or reusability?


I appreciate any insights or suggestions to help refine these source generators and ensure they are effective and maintainable.
